# Convex function - Involves powered quadratic form

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms, non-convex-optimization

I would like to prove/disprove that the following function is convex with respect to $w$:
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln[1+(w^{t}X_iw)^{-y}]
$$

where I have N data points, $w$ is the $p\times 1$ vector, $X_{i}$ is a $p \times p$ diagonal matrix and $y$ is either $-1$ or $+1$.

I got stucked with the powered quadratic form, I have no idea how to deal with this. Online materials do not seem to includ the case of the powered quadratic form. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

It is not convex. Take $N=1$, $p=1$ and $y=-1$. Take $X_1 = 1$. In this case, your function is a one-dimensional function defined by:
$$
\ln[1+w^2]
$$
It is not convex by the second derivative test. You can also plot it and see visually.